# What is the purpose of the UN having multiple conventions on the same thing rather than making amendments to previous conventions?

Tags: united-nations

The UN often has multiple conventions on the same thing ([example](https://www.un.org/en/conferences/drug)). Is there any reason they do this rather than amending a previous convention? e.g. maybe it is harder to make an amendment than a convention, maybe amendments have less power than conventions, tradition, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the initial round of negotiations, nations sign and ratify a convention one by one. They would have to sign and ratify the amendment *again*. So there would be non-member states, members of the original convention but not the amendment, and members of both the original convention and the amendment. After a few rounds of amendments it would be difficult to understand which version applies to which country, and the use of precedent for interpretation would be difficult.